# .Net Core - Redirect Client certificate from Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a Razor Pages app with the certificate authorization and an API service for it with the same authorization. These applications running under Nginx reverse proxy. Nginx also has certificate verification.

I need to redirect Client Certificate from application to an API through HttpClient. Can I redirect that way?

Here's the code I tried

```
private async Task<HttpClient> GetClient()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var cert = await GetCertificate();
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    return client;
}

private async Task<X509Certificate2> GetCertificate()
{
    return await _httpContext.HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();
}
```

But the nginx response that certificate's not provided

```
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
```

I've also tried without proxy but then API doesn't see certificate.
If I add cert to the header manually it works, with forwarding service.

Comment: do you get any solution how to bind different SSL (PFX) certificate file for multi tenant URL?